# Pyodbc: Unable to update table on database (no error)

Tags: python, sql-server, database, odbc, pyodbc

I have:

```
import pyodbc
con_str = "DRIVER={%s};SERVER=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s" % \
          ('FreeTDS','192.168.1.22','myuser','mypass','mydb')
con = pyodbc.connect(con_str)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("update mytable set name='abcd'")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

The code executes and exits without any error !

But the database remains unchanged - nothing happened.

Comment: Try a SELECT; do you get results?

Comment: Yes, I am getting results with `SELECT` queries !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved..

The problem was in the `FreeTDS` driver that I used.
I ran the same script on a windows machine using its native `SQL Server Native Client 10.0` driver.

And it worked GREAT !